# Best Practice: How to address database rows using IDEs autocompletiton

Tags: php, database-design

i'm looking for an 'best practice approach' for addressing database rows. I'm using **PHP**.

I'm working on a settings framework. If a dev wants to know if a specific setting is set he can just call `Settings::getSetting(1);` and he will get the value from the users settings.
The 1 here is the ID of the corresponding database row. ID is the only key in the table and the only unique feature.

My problem is: a dev needs a value from a setting but he doesn't want to look the ID up in the DB. My absolut fav approach would be to use statics: `Settings::getSetting(Settings::SETTING_FONT_SIZE);`

Creating statics implies to care about a mapping and this could result in errors. (Someone is entering a new setting in DB and forgets to also add it to the mapping).

I could create dynamic constants using `define()` but this constants also need to be known (but it is more elegant than dealing with IDs).

Is there a way to address a specific row without caring about a mapping and with code completition inside an IDE?

If necessary, I can change the database table

thank you in advance!

EDIT:

The database table i'm talking about has two columns. The first is the ID (unique, primary, autoincrement) and the second is called 'value' and varchar.

EDIT2:

"forget this, it is not possible what your are looking for" is an acceptable answer :)

Comment: You're wanting to store data in a database and have your IDE know about it?

Comment: First off: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. Secondly: somebody has to know what is *in* the database. If you don't want the developers to do it, you should do it. So you should probably make a mapping.

Comment: In an ideal world only the very core of the application should interface with the database at all; everything else should talk to the application models. Need to get the user's settings? `$user->getSettings()` *should* be all a client developer needs to know... or you could use magic getters/setters so that `$user->getFontSize();` fetches `User::settings['font-size']` for instance - but client developers should never *need* to know the underlying database architecture.

Comment: @Scuzzy: exactly :)

Comment: @Loek: I'm questioning for a best practice. Or just questioning your experience. If this is not allowed here, than i know it now.

Comment: @CD001: that is why i don't want database IDs in php code :) your approach requires the dev to look up the array associativ identifiers. The IDE won't complete this.

Comment: Don't use magic numbers at all and use `name, value` as your database columns…?! You can even and should uniquely index the `name` column.

Comment: Yeah - code completion in the IDE is going to be the kicker. Magento fails at that pretty hard as it relies on *soooooo* many magic methods. I've not found a *good* way to map up an undefined set of values from the database to methods that can be auto-completed by an IDE... theoretically you could auto-generate a PHPDoc block from the database (`/* @var type $value */`) sort of thing, which IDEs can read. But auto-generating comments in your class file, at the right place, seems like a reasonably terrible idea :)

Comment: @deceze - using the name as the primary key is much better than a general auto-incremented integer, yup ... but it doesn't solve the issue of having the IDE auto-complete does it? The developer would still need to know/look up what the possible keys are in the database... though they would have more meaningful names.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answers. I gave up on this, as you all said it is nearly impossible to achieve this. I will go with names as unique feature, so the DB lookup is easy. And a mapping for statics.